# Unable to read data from ReactJS Webpage in Arduino using esp32

Tags: reactjs, arduino, esp8266, esp32

I am creating a **ReactJS** app which consists of input field **'ssid'** and **'Submit'** button. I want to **send this input field data to esp32** on pressing submit. I am receiving data by doing so but it is skipping every second character i.e. If I write "React" and press submit button, Arduino serial output shows "ec??".

React Code (index.js):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class arduinoApp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { ssid: '', password: '' };
  }
  setSsid(state) {
    this.setState({ ssid: state !== '' })
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/inputText')
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(state => this.setSsid(state));
  }
   Submitted(){
    fetch('/inputText', { method: 'PUT', body: document.getElementById('ssid').value})
      .then(response => response.text())
}
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ConfigurePage">
        <div>
          <input type="text" id="ssid" name="ssid" />
          <button type="submit" onClick={this.Submitted} >Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<arduinoApp/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

Arduino Code:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include "aWOT.h"
#include "StaticFiles.h"

char currentLine;
const char* ssid     = "SSID";
const char* password = "PASSWORD";

WiFiServer server(80);
Application app;


void readSsid(Request &req, Response &res) {
  res.print(currentLine);
}

void updateSsid(Request &req, Response &res) {
  while(req.available())
          {
             currentLine+=req.read();
             Serial.write(req.read());
          }
  Serial.println(currentLine);
  return readSsid(req, res);
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);
  IPAddress IP = WiFi.softAPIP();

  Serial.println(IP);

  app.get("/inputText", &readSsid);
  app.put("/inputText", &updateSsid);

  app.route(staticFiles());
  server.begin();
}

void loop() {
  WiFiClient client = server.available();

  if (client.connected()) {
    app.process(&client);
  }
}
```

What I am doing wrong during transferring or reading data from webpage?

Your help would be appreciated! Thanks in Advance.

Comment: i didnt get that skipping of second character can you elaborate the issue

Comment: It only prints characters on even indices of Actual input.

Comment: can you tell an example like if i type "Kainat" in the ssid input box the value is "ant" => even indices of Actual input

Comment: Yep. I have mentioned the example above. In case of 'Kainat', it prints 'ant?' .

Comment: In the UI code i see that the component is uncontrolled but its weird, did you tried the solution posted by @Menilik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on the Arduino code. On updateSsid, your while loop will read two times (the first read data is lost in the process, the second is caught).

Here is a quick fix,

```
void updateSsid(Request &req, Response &res) {
    while(req.available())
    {
         currentLine+=req.read();
         //Serial.write(req.read()); // or remove the above line...
    }
    Serial.println(currentLine);  // if removing currentLine, don't forget here
    return readSsid(req, res);
}
```

OR:

```
void updateSsid(Request &req, Response &res) {
    while(req.available())
    {
        //currentLine+=req.read();
        Serial.write(req.read());
    }
    // Serial.println(currentLine);
    return readSsid(req, res);
}
```